# Headless Google Chrome Doesn't Fire in Windows Server 2016 via ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, impersonation, google-chrome-headless, windows-server-2016

I am trying to generate PDF using Google Chrome Headless, using this code in **ASP.NET Core 2.2**:

```
        string args = $"--headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf={targetFile} {file}";
        string chrome = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";

        ProcessStartInfo inkscapeInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(chrome, args);
        Process inkscape = Process.Start(inkscapeInfo);
        inkscape.WaitForExit(5000);
```

It works great in my local computer and **Visual Studio** but when I upload it to the **Windows 2016 Server** It does't work, I checked the chrome.exe path and it was correct on the server.
Actually I tried some other possible solutions but it seem no **exe** file fires not only headless chrome, what should I do?

Comment: Do you have any error message ?

Comment: Unfortunately no!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution!

1. I added the **IUser_DomainName** user to **administrative** group.
2. I added this user to the **chrome.exe** and give it a full permission.

None of them worked alone!